# No device supported for my android app

Tags: android, google-play

Yesterday morning I published my app on the google playstore, till now it does not occur in the playstore. I published it although there was a comment on the developer console that my app is supported by 0 devices.

I searched about this topic and saw that it might be a bug of the developer console. But now the app cannot be found in the playstore. Maybe its not a bug its a feature :-) and something on my app is the reason for this 0 supported device. I know that there are other stackoverflow topics with that issue but I could not find a solution with these answers

Here is my manifest, what can be the reason for these 0 device

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.al.phaba.myApp"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Location.network" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />

    <application
        android:name="de.al.phaba.myApp.AttachApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/camera"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="false"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="de.al.phaba.myApp.activies.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="de.al.phaba.myApp.activies.ActionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="de.al.phaba.myApp.activies.FormSelectionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="de.al.phaba.myApp.activies.InstanceSelectionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="de.al.phaba.myApp.activies.CommentActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="de.al.phaba.myApp.activies.MultiPhotoSelectActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <!-- <activity android:name="de.al.phaba.myApp.activies.Prefs" /> -->
        <activity
            android:name="de.al.phaba.myApp.activies.SettingsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="de.al.phaba.myApp.activies.InformationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service
            android:name="de.al.phaba.myApp.services.AttachService"
            android:icon="@drawable/loading_icon"
            android:label="@string/attachServiceName"
            android:process=":attachServiceBackground" />

        <receiver
            android:name="de.al.phaba.myApp.AttachmentStartupReceiver"
            android:process=":attachServiceBackground" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

         <activity
             android:name="org.acra.CrashReportDialog"
             android:excludeFromRecents="true"
             android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
             android:launchMode="singleInstance"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />

    </application>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Oh man, I had it too. had to change a little thing... can't remember what, will think hard!

Comment: :-) i know this kind of problem, solved something once and remembering it is not always easy. Hope it works in your case

Comment: try to recompile and upload it without this line `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Location.network" />`
Just to look if this changes anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way.

i have same issue to solve this issue

i add this many lines in Manifest.

```
 <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"   />

    <compatible-screens>

    <!-- small size screens -->
     <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!--Only hdpi and xhdpi for normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

    </compatible-screens>
```

**EDIT:**
   i checked this tag is unusefull remove it from your Manifest.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Location.network" />
```

Comment: yes this was it, it supports now 1683 devices. How long will it normally take to occure in the playstore?

Comment: @Dixit Patel i have done similar things as you mentioned but i still have the same problem.Android supported devices 0